# Group queries with restriction on max/last value

Tags: sql

I have a table 'element' with those columns:

- id (the primary key)
- ref_id (a reference to another table)
- time (the time where the row was added)
- value (the value at the given time for the given ref_id)

I need to get the last value and time for each ref_id.

Currently I do a query for each ref_id in a for who return the correct result:

```
SELECT time, value
FROM element
WHERE ref_id = <ID>
 AND time = (SELECT max(time) FROM element WHERE ref_id = <ID>)
```

However, this take a long time to do multiple queries (around 1s by query). I was looking to do an unique query for all ref_id to try to speed up the overall time.

Is it possible ?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you please print the explain plan of this query? There are multiple possibles solution which can vary from adding an index to having a join between each element and its max value, and also - adding analytic function of max might be a valid solution : https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/min-and-max-analytic-functions

Comment: Hello, thanks for trying to help me. I've added an index who does the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT time, value
FROM element e
WHERE e.time = (SELECT MAX(e2.time) FROM element e2 WHERE e2.ref_id = e.ref_id);
```

Most databases can take advantage of an index for this:  `element(ref_id, time desc)`.

Comment: Hello, first of all, thanks for your answer.

I've tried your solution, however, this query take more time than all queries combined. Each individual query take about 1s. With 13 ref_id, i've stopped this query after 3 m.

The index however speed up by a wide margin the queries, from around 1s to 50ms which is fine for my need.

Thanks a lot !